# Android WebView Video not filling left and right side of landscape + notification bar

Tags: android, webview

I am just making a basic webview program for myself nothing special. I have searched Stack Overflow and got majority of it working but now when in landscape mode there is left and right bar and the video is not filling the window.

Also not sure if there is an easy way to remove the notification bar where the time etc. are.

I can't figure it out.I am at the stuck point, didn't want to ask for help but here I am.

All the code has been shared on hastebin for easier reading

[main activity link](https://hastebin.com/xurehuzego.java)

[this is the mainfest from android studio](https://hastebin.com/cagixuvuda.xml)

[this is the activity main file](https://hastebin.com/zenipipera.xml)

[image: This is what the issue looks like]
[Style Sheet](https://hastebin.com/riredobahe.js)

Answer (score 0):

For navigation bar you can put this code in your onCreate:

```
View rootView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                        if (rootView != null)
                            rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

About "left and right" do you have some default padding? can you set padding 0dp on your RelativeLayout.

Comment: for some reason getActivity(). - errors out not sure what i have to put there..
I have no padding set or whatever none of that stuff

Comment: if you will use it in Activity, `getActivity()` you don't need, start from `getWindow()...`

Comment: beautiful thanks for that, worked fine. i will accept your answer for that part i wish i could figure out the rest it is really starting to annoying me. i changed all the padding to 0 and margins still nothing. Yet it only happens when i click the FULL window view key.. when i don't the video displays  the full width on landscape orientation . I can't figure it out

Comment: on which device you make test? left and right padding on every device? Let's try to find problem with this to.

Comment: Can you add to your question `styles.xml`, I create now clean project, copied your code, run it on virtual pixel with android 9 and all works fine.

Comment: i updated the first post  https://hastebin.com/riredobahe.js i- i am uses pixel xl 2 with the pie update for the emulator